# Check database data

Tags: java, sql, database, azure

I have a database "library_db" hosted on azure, which has a table "admin_db", with the fields "username" and "password". How can I check in java if a certain user is existent in my table? (If a user has been registered and its username and password is present in my table)

I have tried the following:

```
public void LoginAction(String user, String password) {
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, passwordServer);
        SQLServerPreparedStatement preparedStatement = (SQLServerPreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `admin_db` WHERE `username`=? AND `password`=?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        SQLServerResultSet resultSet =preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("login successful");
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Login fail");
    }
```

The code runs without errors, but it executes the catch->Output:Login fail

Comment: I suggest that you add `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch-clause. This will let you see the exact error. Then post the error here if you can't solve it your self.

Comment: @J.A.P, thank you so much! It were the " ' " around the table and field names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
 SQLServerPreparedStatement preparedStatement = (SQLServerPreparedStatement)connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password FROM admin_db WHERE username=? AND password=?");
```